# Oracle next_day function equivalent in JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, function, date, calendar

I wanted to make a method which works similar to as oracle's `next_day()` function, below is my code which accepts date n weekday in MONDAY,TUESDAY etc. and returns a date which falls on the next given day from the input date.

```
/**
 * @param date
 * @param weekDay
 * @return Gives the date for next weekday specified in the parameter.
 */    
public Date getNextDay(Date value, String weekday) {
    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    date1.setTime(value);
        
    if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("MONDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("TUESDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.TUESDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("WEDNESDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("THURSDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.THURSDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("FRIDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.FRIDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else if (weekday.equalsIgnoreCase("SATURDAY")) {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    } else {
        while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    }
                
    return date1.getTime();
}
```

Please suggest a better way of doing this.

Comment: Hello, could explain why this code is not working correctly ?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in a `java.util.Date` or do you want a *better* class as well as a *better way of doing this*?

Comment: @matthiasbe hey this is working for me, i just wanted to know if there is any better way for doing the same

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you do it using the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. The `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In case you are not using Java-8, you can still use Java-8 date-time API through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests

        // Next occurrence
        System.out.println(getNextDay(LocalDate.now(), "Monday"));
        System.out.println(getNextDay(LocalDate.now(), "Wednesday"));

        // Same (if date falls on the given day) or next occurrence
        System.out.println(getSameOrNextDay(LocalDate.now(), "Monday"));
        System.out.println(getSameOrNextDay(LocalDate.now(), "Wednesday"));
    }

    static LocalDate getNextDay(LocalDate value, String weekday) {
        return value.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.valueOf(weekday.toUpperCase())));
    }

    static LocalDate getSameOrNextDay(LocalDate value, String weekday) {
        return value.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.valueOf(weekday.toUpperCase())));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-28
2020-09-30
2020-09-28
2020-09-23
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the **next day** I'll suggest using a `java.time.LocalDate` instead of a `java.util.Date`.

The following code accepts such a `LocalDate` along with a `String` (that needs to be a full day of week in upper case letters) and returns the `LocalDate` representing the nearest future date which has the given day of week:

```
public static LocalDate nextDay(LocalDate sourceDay, String weekday) {
    // parse the day of week to an enum value
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.valueOf(weekday);
    // check if the day is the same as the one of the given LocalDate
    if (sourceDay.getDayOfWeek().equals(dayOfWeek)) {
        // and return the LocalDate that's a week later
        return sourceDay.plusWeeks(1);
    } else {
        // otherwise add a day to the given date
        LocalDate nextDayOfWeek = sourceDay.plusDays(1);
        // and do that until the day of week of the given date is reached
        while (nextDayOfWeek.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
            nextDayOfWeek = nextDayOfWeek.plusDays(1);
        }
        // then return the future date
        return nextDayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

You can use it in a `main` like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(nextDay(LocalDate.now(), "FRIDAY")
                            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd '('EEEE')'",
                                    Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
```

Output (*today* ⇒ `2020-09-23`):

```
2020-09-25 (Friday)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "new" `java.time.DayOfWeek` and `java.time.LocalDate` classes:

```java
public LocalDate getNextDay(
    final LocalDate value,
    final DayOfWeek day
)
{
    int currentDay = value.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    int expectedDay = day.getValue();
    if ( currentDay >= expectedDay )
    {
        expectedDay += 7;
    }
    return value.plusDays( expectedDay - currentDay );
}
```